# Using $wpdb on a different URL

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have a WP installation on one URL - say www.demosite.com/wordpress and I want to call in the posts to a different url on the same sever - say www.demosite.com/foundation.

I see there's the $wpdb function/class and I understand there are various queries I can use to extract specific posts (ie by user).

What I'm struggling with is accessing the db from the different domain. I'm assuming I'll need to give www.demosite.com/foundation a clue as to where to look for the db I want it to access. So I've got a copy of the www.demosite.com/wordpress's config file with all the relevant DB access details. But that currently isn't working on it's own. So I suspect I've missed a fairly basic step somewhere.

So I'm asking if anyone has done something similar before or knows of a good tutorial I can follow please?

I've read quite a few tutorials already and the all seem to assume you're working in/with your current wp installation on the same URL and therefore don't need to config files as they're already connected to the right db.

I apologise if this is php101 type stuff but php really isn't my area of expertise.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/123311/synchronizing-two-wordpress-sites-content).  I think it is what you're trying to accomplish. Or another [here](http://olivier.thereaux.net/2009/02/26/wordpress-sync/)

Comment: I should have mentioned that the second site (for example www.demosite.com/foundation) wont be running Wordpress, simply Foundation as a framework. But thanks for the info, reading through it now.